# F# member constraints + ^a byref parameters

Tags: generics, f#, constraints, ref, byref

After some playing around F# member constraints feature and writing function like this:

```
let inline parse< ^a when ^a : (static member Parse: string -> ^a) > s =
    (^a: (static member Parse: string -> ^a) s)
```

That works perfectly fine:

```
let xs = [ "123"; "456"; "999" ] |> List.map parse<int>
```

I'm trying to write other func `tryParse`, that uses static method `TryParse` and wraps the parse result into `'a option` type for better support in F#. Something like this doesn't compiles:

```
let inline tryParse s =
    let mutable x = Unchecked.defaultof< ^a>
    if (^a: (static member TryParse: string * ^a byref -> bool) (s, &x))
        then Some x else None
```

The error is:

> error FS0001: This expression was
>   expected to have type
>       **byref<'a>**     but here has type
>       **'a ref**

F# `ref`-cells doesn't work too:

```
let inline tryParse s =
    let x = ref Unchecked.defaultof< ^a>
    if (^a: (static member TryParse: string * ^a byref -> bool) (s, x))
        then Some x else None
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yikes, I think this is a bug... also, `TryParse: string -> bool * ^a` doesn't work.

Comment: This appears to be fixed in F# 3.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This appears to be fixed in F# 3.0.

**Old answer:**

I agree with Stephen's comment that it's most likely a bug.  There are many limitations on byref types, so it's not particularly surprising to me that they don't play well with member constraints.  Here's an (ugly) workaround using reflection:

```
type parseDel<'a> = delegate of string * 'a byref -> bool

type Parser< ^a when ^a : (static member TryParse: string * ^a byref -> bool)> private ()=
  static let parser = System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof<parseDel<'a>>, typeof<'a>.GetMethod("TryParse", [|typeof<string>; typeof<'a>.MakeByRefType()|])) :?> parseDel<'a>
  static member inline ParseDel = parser

let inline tryParse (s:string) =
  let mutable x = Unchecked.defaultof< ^a>
  if Parser<_>.ParseDel.Invoke(s, &x) then
    Some x
  else None

let one : int option = tryParse "1"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a bug too, something with member constraints and byref types. I can make a slightly less ugly reflection version by changing the signature of the member constraint:

```
let inline tryParse<'a when 'a : (static member TryParse : string -> 'a byref -> bool)>  s  =
    let args = [| s ; null |]
    if typeof<'a>
        .GetMethod("TryParse", [| typeof<string>; typeof< ^a>.MakeByRefType() |])
        .Invoke(null, args) = box true 
        then Some (args.[1] :?> 'a) 
        else None
```

This one is very close:

```
let inline tryParse< ^a when ^a: (static member TryParse: string -> ^a byref -> bool)> s =
    let mutable x = Unchecked.defaultof<'a>
    if (^a: (static member TryParse: string -> ^a byref -> bool) (s, &x))
        then Some x else None
```

but I get a error *FS0421: The address of the variable 'x' cannot be used at this point* when I try to compile it.

Answer (score 2):

This compiles but still does not work as expected:

```
let inline tryParse< ^a when ^a: (static member TryParse: string -> ^a ref -> bool) > s =
  let x = ref Unchecked.defaultof< ^a>
  match (^a: (static member TryParse: string -> ^a ref -> bool )  (s, x)) with
    | false -> None
    | true -> Some(!x)

// returns [Some 0; Some 0; Some 0; null], so our tryParse is not retrieving the value from the ref
let xs = [ "1"; "456"; "999"; "a" ] |> List.map tryParse<int>
```

in this specific case, rather than using reflection I would just recreate TryParse out of Parse in f#

```
let inline tryParse< ^a when ^a: (static member Parse: string -> ^a) > s =
  try  
    Some(^a: (static member Parse: string -> ^a)  s)
  with
    | exn -> None

let xs = [ "1"; "456"; "999"; "a" ] |> List.map tryParse<int>
```

Comment: I raised this to fsbugs@microsoft.com