# In F#, is it possible to have a tryParse function that infers the target type

Tags: f#, constraints, inline, string-parsing

Presently we do this...

```
let parseDate defaultVal text = 
match DateTime.TryParse s with
| true, d -> d
| _       -> defaultVal
```

Is it possible to do this...

```
let d : DateTime = tryParse DateTime.MinValue "2015.05.01"
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4656864/82959.

Answer (score 18):

Yes. Welcome to the world of member constraints, ref, and byref values.

```
  let inline tryParseWithDefault 
      defaultVal 
      text 
      : ^a when ^a : (static member TryParse : string * ^a byref -> bool) 
      = 
    let r = ref defaultVal
    if (^a : (static member TryParse: string * ^a byref -> bool) (text, &r.contents)) 
    then !r 
    else defaultVal
```

1. `defaultVal` and `text` are formal parameters and will be inferred. Here, `text` is already constrained to be `string` because it is used as the first parameter in a call to the static method, `SomeType.TryParse`, as explain later. `defaultVal` is constrained to be whatever `^a` is since it is a possible result value per the `if..then..else` expression.
2. `^a` is a statically resolved type parameter (vs a generic type parameter of the form `'a`). In particular, `^a` will be resolved at compile time to a specific type. Consequently, the function hosting it must be marked `inline`, which means that each invocation of the function will become an in-place replacement at that invocation with this body of the function, wherein each static type parameter will become a specific type; in this case, whatever type `defaultVal` is. There is no base type or interface type constraints restricting the possible type of `defaultVal`. However, you can provide static and instance member constraints such as is done here. Specifically, the result value (and therefore the type of `defaultVal`) must apparently have a static member called, `TryParse`, that accepts a `string` and a reference to a mutable instance of that type, and returns a `boolean` value. This constraint is made explicit by the stated return type on the line beginning with `: ^a when ...`. The fact that `defaultVal` itself is a possible result constrains it to be of the same type as `^a`. (The constraint is also implicit elsewhere throughout the function which is unnecessary as explained below).
3. `: ^a when ^a : (static ....` describes the result type, `^a`, as having a static member called TryParse of type `string * ^a byref -> bool`. That is to say, the result type must have a static member called `TryParse` that accepts a `string`, a reference to an instance of itself (and therefore a mutable instance), and will return a `boolean` value. This description is how F# matches the .Net definition of TryParse on DateTime, Int32, TimeSpan, etc. types. Note, `byref` is F# equivalent of C#'s `out` or `ref` parameter modifier.
4. `let r = ref defaultVal` creates a reference type and copies the provided value, `defaultVal`, into it. `ref` is one of the ways F# creates mutable types. The other is with the `mutable` keyword. The difference is that mutable stores its value on the stack while ref stores its in main memory/heap and holds an address (on the stack) to it. The latest version of F# will seek to automatically upgrade mutable designations to ref depending on the context, allowing you to code only in terms of mutable.
5. `if (^a : (static...` is an `if` statement over the invocation results of the TryParse method on the statically inferred type, `^a`. This TryParse is passed, `(text, &r.contents)`, per its `(string * ^a byref)` signature. Here, `&r.contents` provides the reference to the mutable content of `r` (simulating C#'s `out` or `ref` parameter) per the expectation of TryParse. Note, we are off the reservation here and certain F# niceties for inter-operating with the .Net framework do not extend out this far; in particular, the automatic rolling up of space separated F# parameters into .net framework function parameters as a tuple is not available. Hence, the parameters are provide to the function as a tuple, `(text, &r.contents)`.
6. `!r` is how you read a reference value. `r.Value` would also work.

The `TryParse` methods provided by .Net seems to always set a value for the out parameter. Consequently, a default value is not strictly required. However, you need a result value holder, `r`, and it must have an initial value, even null. I didn't like null. Another option, of course, is to impose another constraint on `^a` that demands a default value property of some sort.

The following subsequent solution removes the need for a default parameter by using the `Unchecked.defaultof< ^a >` to derive a suitable placeholder value from the "inferred result" type (yes, it feels like magic). It also uses the `Option` type to characterize success and failure obtaining a result value. The result type is therefore, `^a option`.

```
tryParse 
    text 
    : ^a option when ^a : (static member TryParse : string * ^a byref -> bool) 
    = 
  let r = ref Unchecked.defaultof< ^a >
  if (^a : (static member TryParse: string * ^a byref -> bool) (text, &r.contents)) 
  then Some (!r)
  else None
```

And, per @kvb suggestions, the following brevity is possible. In this case, type inference is employed to both stipulate the type constraint on `^a` as a consequence of it's invocation in the `if (^a : ...))` expression and to also establish the type of the mutable buffer `r` for TryParse's out parameter. [I have since come to learn this is how FsControl does some of it's magic](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl/blob/dc8b41a5b7f50f5adc419512df8efce0801c4351/FsControl.Core/Converter.fs#L86)

```
let inline tryParse text : ^a option = 
  let mutable r = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
  if (^a : (static member TryParse: string * ^a byref -> bool) (text, &r)) 
  then Some r
  else None

let inline tryParseWithDefault defaultVal text : ^a = 
  match tryParse text with
  | Some d -> d
  | _      -> defaultVal
```

Wherein the usage would be...

```
> let x:DateTime option = tryParse "December 31, 2014";;
val x : DateTime option = Some 2014-12-31 12:00:00 a.m.

> let x:bool option = tryParse "false";;
val x : bool option = Some false

> let x:decimal option = tryParse "84.32";;    
val x : decimal option = Some 84.32M
```

For the case of using type constraints on instance member such as type constraining for Fsharp's dynamic member lookup operator, `?`, such that the type of its target must contain a `FindName:string -> obj` member for use in resolving member lookup requests, the syntax is as follows:

```
let inline (?) (targetObj:^a) (property:string) : 'b =
    (^a : (member FindName:string -> obj) (targetObj, property)) :?> 'b
```

Note:

1. The signature of instance methods must explicitly specify their `self` object, which is normally a hidden first parameter of object methods
2. This solution also promotes the result to the type of `'b`

A sample usage would be the following:

```
let button : Button = window?myButton
let report : ReportViewer = window?reportViewer1
```

Comment: In F#+ is that function defined in a similar way and also the partial version `parse` https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus/blob/24f6501d7c6449e0eb06c993ad247c8f1db5a3f6/FSharpPlus/Operators.fs#L261

Comment: As a minor style comment, using `let mutable x = Unchecked.defaultof<_>` and then using `&x` as the argument to the method call seems cleaner to me than introducing an actual `ref` value; also, the signature can be inferred from the definition (so you don't have to write out the constraint twice), though perhaps you included it for pedagogical reasons.

Comment: @Gustavo I was not aware of the FSharpPlus project and only passingly of FsControl. Thanks for opening my eyes. They did define TryParse is a similar but more elegant way :)

https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl/blob/dc8b41a5b7f50f5adc419512df8efce0801c4351/FsControl.Core/Converter.fs#L86

Comment: @kvb Thanks for your insight. The use of member constraints to invoke methods (static and instance) was not immediately obvious to me from the MSDN material. I was surprise when I uncovered it. I have added an example incorporating your 'stylistic' suggestions.